# Is it possible to add a keyframe to an IK control's Target Root?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, keyframes, actions

I have an animation file with multiple actions, and I'm using the Mr. Mannequin rig for Unreal.

For all of my previous actions, the Target Root (found in the Rigging Modules settings) of my IK hand control is set to the rig's root.  For my most recent action, however, I want to change the Target Root to be set to the rig's pelvis (imagine the rig's hand on its hip, for instance).  When I do this, it changes the Target Root across all actions, not just the current action.  It doesn't look like a keyable setting, unfortunately.

Is there anything I can do to make this setting apply only to this specific action?  Is it possible to add a keyframe to this setting?

(Note: I have reasons for not using FK for the hand when its Target Root is set to the rig's root.)

Thanks!

Chris

Comment: Rigging module settings?  Are you using an addon?  You might want to specify that in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly new to Blender and assumed this was a common menu.  I'm using the Mr. Mannequin rig, which I just noted above.  I wonder whether these settings come with this rig, or maybe it's a Rigify thing, not sure.

Comment: Yeah, I just confirmed with the rig's creator that it's specific to the rig and non-keyable.  They suggested a "Child of" constraint to the pelvis, which worked like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed with the rig's creator that the setting in question is specific to the rig and non-keyable. They suggested a "Child of" constraint on the hand IK control to the pelvis, which worked like a charm.  For anyone using the Mr. Mannequin rig for game animation in Unreal, check out their Discord server. :)